# Impossible to import Acumatica Customization package undefined: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined

Tags: acumatica

I want to import some customization packages I have created for Acumatica, but, when I try to import (click on import button on SM204505 screen) I receive a message "undefined: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined"

Have you ever seen this message? does somebody know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I encountered this last night and have been troubleshooting ever since.  I have not found a solution, but might have a possible workaround  (I am not an experienced coder - please excuse any faux pas...)

1 - Under System Management > Companies, make sure your company has a company name (in addition to a company login name).  Training materials say that this serves as the top-level node in the company tree and is needed to import customization projects.  However, "Company," was already in my Company Name field and I still got the error.

2 - I was logged in as administrator and found under User Security > Access Rights by Role, that access for Administrator was set as 'Revoked' under System > Customization > Work Area > Manage.  I changed that to 'Delete.'  Also, under source code, I set my access rights to 'Insert.'

I still got the error, but chose to include the above in case they affect the following workaround:

3 - The customization project .zip file I was trying to import contained XML code.  On the Customization Projects screen (SM204505), I added a row and a project name, then saved it.  After clicking on the project name link, the Customized Screens screen opened (AU201000).  Under the File menu, I selected Edit Project XML, copy/pasted it onto the screen, then clicked Upload Package.  (It seems that using Choose File then Upload Package also works for me).  Then I Saved to Database.  I published from that screen - I did not try it back on the Customization Projects screen.

Even if your case is not as simple, maybe there is a similar workaround along those lines.